# Mongodb C# driver - can't use admin authentication to access other databases

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

When you login as admin user (user of admin database) in MongoDB console, you can then have full access to any database on the same server without need to login to each of them. 
But, if I use the official C# driver and provide connection string to admin database, then when I am trying to access any other database, I get authentication error. It's happening in MongoServerInstance.AcquireConnection() where it's trying to re-authenticate the connection and checks admin database credentials against the other database which of course fails.

What I'm trying to achieve is - I provide admin connection string and get access to all databases without the need to login to each and every one of them, exactly like the console does

Anything I can do to make C# driver work the same way as the console does in terms of authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I digged into MongoDB driver's authentication code, I found that you need to add '(admin)' after admin username in the connection string to tell the driver that this is in fact an admin login. After doing that everything works as expected!

Comment: bah, imagine. where you found it ;) +1

Comment: @Andrew - deep down the source code. One would think it should have been documented...

Comment: can you please give an example connection string? was this to use an adminAnyDatabase user?

Comment: So is it possible to have separate credentials for each database with the C# driver?  I saw another SO post that said yes by using the GetDatabase() call, but in contrast to that post that call does not have an overload that accepts credentials, only a second parameter that is a MongoDatabaseSettings object.